# Scrollview containing recyclerview and viewpager not scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

I have a piece of xml code in which I have a nestedScrollView and below is a recyclerview and below that is a viewpager which has two fragments and both of these fragments contain recyclerviews 
the issue I am facing is that the recyclerviews are scrolling but the main layout is not scrolling. I am asking the question after a lot of searching but seems like I'm stuck.
I tried these
    1. scrollview with only one child layout
    2. scrollview width and height to be fill_parent

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".homeScreen.fragments.home.baseFragment.Home">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/home_screen_banner">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
            android:alpha="0.6"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeFragmentHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_80sdp"
            android:text="Find Your Dream Job"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@color/mainOrangeColor" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_240sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/homeFragmentSearchField"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_190sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
                android:focusedByDefault="false"
                android:hint="search keyword..."
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/homeFragmentSearchLl"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@color/mainOrangeColor"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@+id/homeFragmentHeader">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:text="Select"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:text="Category"
                            android:textColor="@color/mainOrangeColor"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:background="@color/mainOrangeColor" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_7sdp"
                            android:elevation="@dimen/_16sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_left"
                            android:tint="@color/mainOrangeColor" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_7sdp"
                            android:elevation="@dimen/_16sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_right"
                            android:tint="@color/mainOrangeColor" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/homeFragmentRv"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

                        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                            android:id="@+id/homeFragmentTabLayout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/mainOrangeColor"
                            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/mainOrangeColor"
                            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorGrey" />

                        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/homeFragmentViewPager"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_below="@+id/homeFragmentHeader">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
```

RelativeLayout height match_parent
NestedScrollView height has to be wrap_content
And child ViewHroups height has to be wrap_content

at the end it supose to look something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/home_screen_banner">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
            android:alpha="0.6"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeFragmentHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_80sdp"
            android:text="Find Your Dream Job"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@color/mainOrangeColor"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_240sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/homeFragmentSearchField"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_190sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
                android:focusedByDefault="false"
                android:hint="search keyword..."
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/homeFragmentSearchLl"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@color/mainOrangeColor"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_search"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/homeFragmentHeader">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:text="Select"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:text="Category"
                    android:textColor="@color/mainOrangeColor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@color/mainOrangeColor"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/_16sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_left"
                    android:tint="@color/mainOrangeColor"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/_16sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_right"
                    android:tint="@color/mainOrangeColor"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/homeFragmentRv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/homeFragmentTabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/mainOrangeColor"
                    app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/mainOrangeColor"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorGrey"/>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/homeFragmentViewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: no it didn't, when i use wrap_content for height of scrollview, the viewpager's fragments are not visible

Comment: okay then take ScrollView from RelativeLayout, it might block it from scroll

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: Updated again, try it out. Your layout is really complex, my advice would be start using ConstraintLayout